# How to exclude one specific file from being hashed through bash script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I actually try to run recursive through a folder structure and make md5sum on all files into a single md5checksums file.

Heres my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -f md5checksums
find -type f -exec md5sum "{}" + > md5checksums
```

My problem now is that the file md5checksums is aswell running through md5sum and i cant get my head around it how to prevent that. Beside that the script does already what it should do. Anyone who can help me out?

Comment: Simple way: keep your `md5checksums` file in the parent directory.

Comment: Well that doesn really cut it, i have not in all cases access to the parent directory, and aswell running `md5sum -c md5checksums` from parent directory would fail all files because of wrong paths.

Comment: If you stored it in the parent directory, you'd obviously run `md5sums -c ../md5checksums`, wouldn't you?

Comment: sure, just like i said i not have in all cases i need that script the ability to access and write into parent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make the script take the name of that **specific file** you want excluded as argument.

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -f md5checksums
find -type f ! -iname "$1" -exec md5sum "{}" + > md5checksums
```

call the script with `./script "md5checksums"`

Comment: Thats what i was looking for :) changed my line to `find -type f ! -iname "md5checksums" -exec md5sum "{}" + > md5checksums` and now it works like a breeze, thank you

Comment: why -iname instead of -name? why even have it as an argument, when the name of the file is md5checksums?

Comment: You missed the little `!` which means not also is aswell equal to `-not -name`. But to be honest i kinda feel embarassed that i wasnt able to stumble onto that simple solution on my own.

Comment: @tlund : I put the -iname instead of -name just in case he calls the script with the file name in all caps or something.
but since he prefers to have the filename hardcoded in the script it makes no difference :) 
I made the script take the filename as an argument in case the filename was something not consistent every time he calls his hash script.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to avoid conflicts involving redirections to a file affecting the command would be to use [`sponge`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/sponge.1.html) from moreutils:

```
sponge  reads  standard  input and writes it out to the specified file.
Unlike a shell redirect, sponge soaks up all its input  before  opening
the  output file. This allows constructing pipelines that read from and
write to the same file.
```

The effect is that the file, if not present already, isn't created until the pipeline finishes.
So:

```
find . -type f -exec md5sum {} + | sponge md5checksums
```

Answer (score 2):

Using only `bash`:

Using `GLOBIGNORE`:

```
$ GLOBIGNORE='md5checksums'  ## Pattern to ignore
$ shopt -s globstar  ## Recursive globbing
$ { for i in **/*; do [ -f "$i" ] && md5sum "$i"; done ;} >md5checksums
```

---

Using `extglob`:

```
$ shopt -s extglob ## Enables extended pattern matching, enabled by default
$ shopt -s globstar
$ { for i in **/!(md5checksums); do [ -f "$i" ] && md5sum "$i"; done ;} >md5checksums
```

---

Using `zsh`:

```
% setopt extended_glob 
% { for i in **/^md5checksums(.); do md5sum "$i"; done  ;} >md5checksums
```

- `zsh` does recusive matching by default while using `**`
- `^md5checksums` is `zsh` extended glob pattern, meaning to match everything else except `md5checksums`
- The glob qualifier `(.)` restricts matches to regular files only.

Answer (score 1):

Another one that do what you want:

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -f md5checksums
find -type f -not -name "md5checksums" -exec md5sum "{}" + > md5checksums
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @heemayl for some nice inspiration in his answer.

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s globstar

rm -f md5checksums

for i in **/*; do
    if [ ! -f "$i" -o "$i" = md5checksums -o "$i" = this_script.sh ]; then
        continue
    else
        md5sum "$i" >> md5checksums
    fi
done
```